# expand and collapse row for ng-table not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to achieve an expand and collapse row for ng-table, basically what I want is if you click on row it expands with more detail.But currently all the rows get expanded on click. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Any help appreciated thanks

```html
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped">
  <tr ng-repeat-start="ticket in ng">
    <td data-title="'Id'">{{ticket.requestId}}</td>
    <td style="width:60%;" data-title="'Subject'" ><a href="#" rel="nofollow" ui-sref="app.detail({id: ticket.requestId})">{{ticket.subject}}</a></td>
    <td data-title="'State'"><span ng-class="ticket.state+'Color'">{{ticket.state}}</span></td>
    <td data-title="'Priority'">{{ticket.priority}}</td>
    <td >
      <a ui-sref="app.detail({id: ticket.requestId})" class="btn btn-transparent btn-xs" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
    <!-- <a  class="btn btn-transparent btn-xs tooltips" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Expand" ng-click="toggleDetail($index);lastComment(ticket.requestId)"><i class="fa"  >+/-</i></a>-->
      <button ng-if="user.expanded" ng-click="user.expanded = false">-</button>
      <button ng-if="!user.expanded" ng-click="user.expanded = true">+</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-if="user.expanded" ng-repeat-end="" >
            <td colspan="8" >Test</td> 
                
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put your variable `expanded` for your line instead of a general var. It means that it won't be `user.expanded` but it have to be `ticket.expanded`

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped">
  <tr ng-repeat-start="ticket in ng">
    <td data-title="'Id'">{{ticket.requestId}}</td>
    <td style="width:60%;" data-title="'Subject'" ><a href="#" rel="nofollow" ui-sref="app.detail({id: ticket.requestId})">{{ticket.subject}}</a></td>
    <td data-title="'State'"><span ng-class="ticket.state+'Color'">{{ticket.state}}</span></td>
    <td data-title="'Priority'">{{ticket.priority}}</td>
    <td >
      <a ui-sref="app.detail({id: ticket.requestId})" class="btn btn-transparent btn-xs" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
    <!--    <a  class="btn btn-transparent btn-xs tooltips" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Expand" ng-click="toggleDetail($index);lastComment(ticket.requestId)"><i class="fa"  >+/-</i></a>-->
      <button ng-if="ticket.expanded" ng-click="ticket.expanded = false">-</button>
      <button ng-if="!ticket.expanded" ng-click="ticket.expanded = true">+</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-if="ticket.expanded" ng-repeat-end="" >
            <td colspan="8" >Test</td> 

</tr>
</table>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/atj0a0pu/)